# Visualizing a huge correlation matrix in python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, correlation

I have hundreds of features and I want to visualize their correlation in Python. But the code below does not display all feature captions in the chart. What solution do you suggest?

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',')
sns.heatmap(df.corr())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Try to adjust figsize and dpi.

Comment: @Frightera Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: I meant `plt.figure(figsize, dpi)`. Did you try to increase the size etc?

Comment: @Frightera Thanks, it works! I recommend you answer with the example to marked as an approved solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without figsize & dpi, seems so collapsed.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot = True, fmt = '.2f')
```

[image]

For to make it more readable, adjust figsize & dpi according to your needings. That's max dpi and figsize I can use for this example df otherwise it exceeds 2MB

```
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(36,36), dpi = 480)
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot = True, fmt = '.2f')
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to only show correlations higher than a +/- threshold?

Comment: You want to show or you want to add as a column to the heatmap? Showing and adding them may consist different things. When you show there may be blank columns in the heatmap I mean.